# Create bootstrap form with multiple inline lables and selects

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

[image: Office hours form]

I'm trying to create a form in bootstrap 4 which looks similar to the image above.

I have tried numerous layouts and played around with the grid system to get the same effect, if I use the grid system to align all elements it looks fine on desktop, but is broken on mobile.

```
<div class="form-row">      
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label id="monday">Monday</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                        <label id="mon-from">From</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">                       
                            <select class="form-control-sm" id="mon-from-hrs" name="mon-from-hrs">
                                <option value="00">00</option>
                                <option value="01">01</option>
                                <option value="02">02</option>
                                <option value="03">03</option>
                                <option value="04">04</option>
                                <option value="05">05</option>
                                <option value="06">06</option>
                                <option value="07">07</option>
                                <option value="08" selected>08</option>
                                <option value="09">09</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>  
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                <option value="23">23</option>
                            </select>
                            <label id="mon-semi-from">:</label>
                            <select class="form-control-sm" id="mon-from-min" name="mon-from-min">
                                <option value="00" selected>00</option>
                                <option value="01">01</option>
                                <option value="02">02</option>
                                <option value="03">03</option>
                                <option value="04">04</option>
                                <option value="05">05</option>
                                <option value="06">06</option>
                                <option value="07">07</option>
                                <option value="08">08</option>
                                <option value="09">09</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>  
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                <option value="23">23</option>
                                <option value="24">24</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="26">26</option>
                                <option value="27">27</option>
                                <option value="28">28</option>
                                <option value="29">29</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="31">31</option>
                                <option value="32">32</option>
                                <option value="33">33</option>
                                <option value="34">34</option>
                                <option value="35">35</option>  
                                <option value="36">36</option>
                                <option value="37">37</option>
                                <option value="38">38</option>
                                <option value="39">39</option>
                                <option value="40">40</option>
                                <option value="41">41</option>
                                <option value="42">42</option>
                                <option value="43">43</option>
                                <option value="44">44</option>
                                <option value="45">45</option>
                                <option value="46">46</option>
                                <option value="47">47</option>
                                <option value="49">49</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                                <option value="51">51</option>  
                                <option value="52">52</option>
                                <option value="53">53</option>
                                <option value="54">54</option>
                                <option value="55">55</option>
                                <option value="56">56</option>
                                <option value="57">57</option>
                                <option value="58">58</option>
                                <option value="59">59</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                        <label id="mon-to">To</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <select class="form-control-sm" id="mon-to-hrs" name="mon-to-hrs">
                                <option value="00">00</option>
                                <option value="01">01</option>
                                <option value="02">02</option>
                                <option value="03">03</option>
                                <option value="04">04</option>
                                <option value="05">05</option>
                                <option value="06">06</option>
                                <option value="07">07</option>
                                <option value="08">08</option>
                                <option value="09">09</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>  
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17" selected>17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                <option value="23">23</option>
                            </select>
                            <label id="mon-semi-to">:</label>
                            <select class="form-control-sm" id="mon-to-min" name="mon-to-min">
                                <option value="00" selected>00</option>
                                <option value="01">01</option>
                                <option value="02">02</option>
                                <option value="03">03</option>
                                <option value="04">04</option>
                                <option value="05">05</option>
                                <option value="06">06</option>
                                <option value="07">07</option>
                                <option value="08">08</option>
                                <option value="09">09</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>  
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                <option value="23">23</option>
                                <option value="24">24</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="26">26</option>
                                <option value="27">27</option>
                                <option value="28">28</option>
                                <option value="29">29</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="31">31</option>
                                <option value="32">32</option>
                                <option value="33">33</option>
                                <option value="34">34</option>
                                <option value="35">35</option>  
                                <option value="36">36</option>
                                <option value="37">37</option>
                                <option value="38">38</option>
                                <option value="39">39</option>
                                <option value="40">40</option>
                                <option value="41">41</option>
                                <option value="42">42</option>
                                <option value="43">43</option>
                                <option value="44">44</option>
                                <option value="45">45</option>
                                <option value="46">46</option>
                                <option value="47">47</option>
                                <option value="49">49</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                                <option value="51">51</option>  
                                <option value="52">52</option>
                                <option value="53">53</option>
                                <option value="54">54</option>
                                <option value="55">55</option>
                                <option value="56">56</option>
                                <option value="57">57</option>
                                <option value="58">58</option>
                                <option value="59">59</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2" id="chkMon">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="closedMon">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="closedMon">Closed</label>                          
                        </div>
                        <label id="mon24Text" hidden></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <a href="javascript: specialMon();" id="specialHrsMon">Add special hours</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This works fine on desktop and laptop screens, but is totally broken on mobile, with the select elements cut off.

Can someone please show me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

use media queries to style the mobile view.
for eg:

```
@media(min-width:320px)and(max-width:768px){
.form-group{
width:100%;
display:block;
}
}
```

manually customise like this.